# bol.com api integration with laravel I need to get product details

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-api

here is the link which has been used

https://api.bol.com/retailer/public/Retailer-API/index.html

I have to get order details and single orders with offers but I need to get product details with an image.

I have read all the docs and understood that. I just need the get API of the product, not the post API.

This website gets the product from bol.com API. I need to get product details same like this website.

here is screenshot

[image]

anyone here who works on bol.com API.
please need help it's important.

thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

you need to build scrapper to fetch information from bol.com using crawler
we did as well,
please find on github this repo
"Ultimate Web Scraper Toolkit"
using url you can fetch images here but we fetching more information

```
function searchByURL($url){
    $res = [];
    $res['product_url']=$url;
    $data = getCode($url);

    // Product Title
    $rows = $data[1]->Find("h1.page-heading span.u-mr--xs");
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $res['title'] = strip_tags((string)$row);
    }

    // Product Image
    $rows = $data[1]->Find("div.image-slot img");
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $res['product_image'] = HTTP::ConvertRelativeToAbsoluteURL($data[0], $row->src);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://pypi.org/project/bol/#description

```
pr = BolShop._product('8739822845244')

print('---------------')
pp.pprint(pr)


im=BolShop._product_images('8739822845244')
print('---------------')
pp.pprint(im)
```

_product_images()

```
def _product_images(self, ean):
    """Fetch product details by ean""" 
    #https://api.bol.com/retailer/public/redoc/v9/retailer.html#operation/get-product-assets
    #https://api.bol.com/retailer/products/{ean}/assets

    uri = self.BASE_URL + "/products/" + str(ean) + "/assets"
    return self._get(uri)
```